# How can I show that this piecewise linear map $T$ is continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $V=L^1([0,2])$ be space of integrable functions, equipped with the norm:

$$\lVert f(x)\rVert=\int_0^2\vert f(x) \vert dx$$

Consider the linear mapping:

$$T: V \to V, [Tf](x):=\begin{cases} f(x+1) & \text{for} &x\in(0,1] \\f(x-1) & \text{for} & \text{elsewhere} \end{cases}$$

Question: How can I show that this is continuous? For a piecewise function I would just check if the values of the two functions at the point $x=1$ is the same. However, I don't have explicit functions here. What to I need to do to show $T$ is continuous or not?

Sample solution from an old exam (I am just not sure whats being done here):

[image]

> a) $$\lVert T\rVert=\sup_{\substack{f\neq0\\ f\in V}}\frac{\lVert Tf\rVert}{\lVert f\rVert}=\sup\frac{\int_0^1\left\lvert f\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right\rvert~\mathrm{d}x+\int_1^2\left\lvert f\left(x\right)\right\rvert~\mathrm{d}x}{\int_0^2\left\lvert f\left(x\right)\right\rvert~\mathrm{d}x}\leq2\cdot\frac{\int_0^2\left\lvert f\left(x\right)\right\rvert~\mathrm{d}x}{\int_0^2\left\lvert f\left(x\right)\right\rvert~\mathrm{d}x}=2<\infty$$ $\implies$ continuous
>
> b) $\sup$: find function s.t. $\lVert T\rVert$ is maximal: $$f_m(x)=\begin{cases}\lambda,&1\leq x\leq \frac{3}{2},\\ 0&\text{else},\end{cases}$$ $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, $\lambda\neq0$. $$\lVert T\rVert=\frac{\lVert Tf_m\rVert}{\lVert f_m\rVert}=\frac{\int_0^1\left\lvert f_m\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right\rvert~\mathrm{d}x+\int_1^2\left\lvert f_m\left(x\right)\right\rvert~\mathrm{d}x}{\int_0^2\left\lvert f_m\left(x\right)\right\rvert~\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\lvert\lambda\rvert\cdot0.5+\lvert\lambda\rvert\cdot 0.5}{\lvert\lambda\rvert\cdot0.5}=2$$

Comment: You show it by noting that $\lVert f\circ g\lVert=\lVert f\lVert$ where $g$ swaps $(0,1]$ with $(1,2]$. Btw, I assume you meant "$V=$", not "$V\in$", and also integral limits don't match $V$ definition.

Comment: The behaviour of $[Tf]$ at $x$ is completely irrelevant to determine whether the linear map $T$ is continuous. Do you know what it means for $T$ to be bounded? What is the connection to continuity? Do you understand what $T$ does graphically?

Comment: @JanBohr I actually don't fully understand what it mean for $T$ to be bounded. I was hoping to get a definition or idea as a starting point so that I can work with that. The transformation shifts the function to the left and right by $1$ respectively.

Comment: @Nullspace a linear operator is bounded if it maps bounded subsets to bounded subsets. Or equivalently there is $M$ such that $\lVert T(x)\rVert\leq M\cdot\lVert x\rVert$ for any $x$. Which is furthermore equivalent to $T$ being continuous. This is a fundamental concept in functional analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *linear* map $T:E\to F,$ where $E,F$ are normed vector spaces, is continuous iff
$$\exists C\in\Bbb R\quad\forall f\in E\quad\|T(f)\|_F\le C\|f\|_E$$
([it is a theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator#Equivalence_of_boundedness_and_continuity), not a definition).

Here, $E=F=L^1([0,2])$ and $\|f\|=\int_0^2|f(x)|\,dx.$
$$\|T(f)\|=\int_0^2|(Tf)(x)|\,dx=\int_0^1|f(x+1)|\,dx+\int_1^2|f(x-1)|\,dx$$
$$=\int_1^2|f(u)|\,du+\int_0^1|f(v)|\,dv=\|f\|$$
(i.e. $T$ is an *isometry*), so you may take $C=1.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I get it now. I have a question regarding the bounds of integration. I posted a sample solution where $T$ is piecewise defined on $[0,1]$ and $[1,2]$ and the norm is defined on [0,2]. In the question I posted, everything is the same except $f(x-1)$ is defined "elsewhere". Since the norm is defined on the interval $[0,2]$ in both questions, is "elsewhere" just synonymous with [1,2] here?

Comment: Yes. More precisely it is not $f(x-1)$ which is defined "elsewhere", it is $Tf(x)$ when $x\notin(0,1].$ And "elsewhere" is $[0,2]\setminus(0,1]=\{0\}\cup(1,2]$ but adding or removing a point does not change integrals. In the sample solution of analogous problem you inserted, the map and its norm are a little more complicated than in your present question.

Comment: I have a quick follow up question (not sure if i should make it a seperate question). How would I go about finding the operator norm $\lVert T \rVert$? I know that it is defined as $$\lVert T \rVert= \sup \frac{\lVert Tf\rVert}{\lVert f\rVert}$$. But I don't have any idea what $f$ is. Do I just assume that $f=const.$?

Comment: This sup is taken over all non-zero $f$'s of the domain of $T.$ Equivalently: all the $f$'s of norm $\le1,$ or all the $f$'s of norm $=1$ (these three sups are equal). It is sometimes attained for some $f$'s (like in the two $T$'s of your post) but not necessarily. If it is not, you have to find some sequence $(f_n)$ with $\|f_n\|=1$ and $\|Tf_n\|\to$ this sup.

Answer (score 1):

You could just go down to the definition of continuity:

> $T$ is continuous if, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that if $\|f-g\| < \delta$, then $\|Tf - Tg\| < \epsilon$.

To start off, I would just write what $\|Tf - Tg\|$ is equal to, and see where that takes me. Notice that it is equal to

$$\int_{-1}^1 |(Tf)(x) - Tg(x)|dx = \int_{-1}^0|(Tf)(x) - (Tg)(x)|dx + \int_{0}^1|(Tf)(x) - (Tg)(x)|dx$$

Now we know that in the first interval, $(Tf)(x) = f(x+1)$ and $(Tg)(x)=g(x+1)$, and similarly for the second interval, so that simplifies to
$$\int_{-1}^0|f(x+1) - g(x+1)|dx + \int_{0}^1|f(x-1) - g(x-1)|dx$$

The next steps, I leave to you, with a hint that you might want to consider some sort of change of variables in the two integrals :).

**Hint 2**: In the first integral, susbtitute $y=x+1$ and in the second, substitute $y=x-1$. Then, take a look at what you get and compare it to $\|Tf - Tg\|$.

Comment: Thank yo for your answer. So am I trying to show that the last line is $< \infty$? Or what is my "end goal"? I added a sample solution to my question that we got from our professor for a very similar problem. The approach seems very different. Am I essentially showing the same here or is the sample solution a different approach?

Comment: @Nullspace No, you want the equality to be smaller than $\epsilon$, and the tool you have available is that you can set $\|Tf-Tg\|$ as small as you want. I added another hint. Please follow it and let me know if something is still unclear.

Comment: I think I got it: $\int_0^{-1} \vert f(x+1)-g(x+1)\vert dx+\int_0^1 \lvert f(x-1)-g(x-1) \rvert dx= \int_0^{-1}\lvert f(y)-g(y)\rvert dy+\int_0^1 \lvert f(y)-g(y) \rvert dy=\int_{-1}^1 \lvert f(y)-g(y)\rvert=\lVert f(y)-g(y) \rVert$ So I just set $f-g< \epsilon$?

Comment: The limits $-1,0,1$ for the integrals in this answer must be replaced by $0,1,2.$

Comment: @Nullspace Exactly! Well done!